# Web App: What technology should I use for a web-app which uses 90% only the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

What technology should I use for a web-app which uses 90% only the keyboard?

I want a web-app which uses most of the time only the keyboard. Which technology could offer me this facility?

I don't care if is a java framework or something based on .net or etc. :)

Answer (score 3):

Really doesn't matter. Use of keyboard on a web page is a client side behaviour / event. If the standard tab ordering of things and adding `tabindex` to elements doesn't give you the control you need, or you have advanced keyboard actions then you will need javascript to help you.

There are javascript frameworks and plugins to help.

See:

- [Handling keyboard events with JavaScript](http://www.webappers.com/2011/10/11/handling-keyboard-events-with-lightweight-javascript/)
- [JS Hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/)
- [jQee jQuery keyboard shortcuts](http://codecanyon.net/item/jqee-keyboard-shortcuts-for-jquery/1930338)
- [15 jQuery keyboard plugins](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:43Y6nmWzbGgJ%3awww.jquery4u.com/plugins/15-keyboard-event-plugins/+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au)